# Команда которая изменяет буквы из сообщения пользователя-вопрос]

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

я бы хотел сделать команду для бота, например, человек вводит /per, бот отвечает " Напишите сообщение ", человек пишет например "Привет", а бот присылает в ответ это же сообщение только с заменёнными буквами, ну например " Прмыет " ну что бы буквы были записанны именно те которые в коде, а не рандом, да это наверное уже прям заказ.. Или же подскажите как это реализовать, если не можете, просто ответьте нет и тд, спасибо если поможете.

Comment: Сначала вам нужно самостоятельно попробовать разобраться, а после уже с набитыми шишками запрашивать помощи. Например, открыть документацию по библиотеке бота. Там посмотреть примеры. Вот эхо-бот: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#a-simple-echo-bot, он возвращает в ответ сообщение пользователя, это половина вашей задачи. Вторая половина это рандом за это отвечает модуль `random`

Comment: А если мне надо что бы не рандом было

Comment: А понял вы про это `ну что бы буквы были записанны именно те которые в коде, а не рандом`, ну тогда это еще проще - добавите переменную с заготовленными сообщениями-ответами и будете отправлять их

Comment: Не совсем понял, просто я хочу сделать типо шифрование слов, человек вводит команду, и вводит какое-то слово, ну или несколько слов, а бот говорит зашифрованное(ые) слово(а) специальными записанными буквами в самом коде, я новичок в питоне, и думал что надо делать типо if/elif message.text == 'буква':, а потом понял что это не правильно когда тестировал..